# Dynamic list of arrays to work on next array if first is busy

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Alright i have a list of Arrays where each array contains a certain amount of data:

```
static List<string[]> result = Etikeketter(arrEtikets, 20);
```

my objective is to work on each of the arrays meaning if the result[0] is busy doing work i want my result[1] to continue the next command.

Now i have tried the following:

```
 var listOfEtiketGroups = result;
        bool isGroupUsed = false;

        while (isGroupUsed == false)
        {
            var firstAvailableGroup = listOfEtiketGroups.FirstOrDefault();
            isGroupUsed = true;

            foreach (var item in firstAvailableGroup)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item); 
            };
```

this works as intended when it comes to how it treats the data in the FirstOrDefault array.

My issue is that when running it, it will take only from my result[0] so it never prints data from result[x]

i have tried an if statement to handle job requests while my boolean was true, but this does the same thing and still only prints from result[0]

Any ideas on how i can get it to work from the next array while first is busy?

Comment: you would have to have an "isused" per group, not just 1 otherwise a group is in use, it doesnt say which

Comment: If you don't use multi-threading, why should an array "be busy"?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just iterate over the list?

Comment: it only interacts with result[0] because that's exactly what you're telling it to do. Right after you grab result[0] (`FirstOrDefault`), you set `isGroupUsed = true`, thus stopping your `while` loop after this iteration.

Comment: 1. How can an array be busy on its own? 2. `FirstOrDefault` always returns the first element `result[0]` since you have not specified any predicate. Moreover it will always be the same element since you do not remove it from the `result` after processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As far as I understood your question, the first your mistake is here
       bool isGroupUsed = false;

   ```
   while (isGroupUsed == false)
   {
       ....
       var firstAvailableGroup = listOfEtiketGroups.FirstOrDefault();
       **isGroupUsed = true;**
       ....
   }
   ```

   During the first pass of your cycle you setting your variable as TRUE and, of course, your cycle stops.
2. If you don't use multithreading, in order to mark your array as busy I propose the next structure:

   ```
   public class MarkedArray {
           public MarkedArray(  int size ) {
                 Busy = false;
                 Array = new string[size];
           }
           public bool Busy {get;set;}
           public string[] Array  {get;set;}
   }

   static List<MarkedArray> result = Etikeketter(arrEtikets, 20);
   ```

Comment: your first solution is some what, what i'm looking for, as i am "trying" to work in multithreading but i'm not sure how to do the code for it to do work on 0 and then continue work on 1, 2 etc depending on the demand

Comment: So, probably you need to use mutexes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a nested for-loop?

```
foreach(var etiketGroup in listOfEtiketGroups)
{
    foreach (var item in etiketGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```